# NEC asic information from around 1990

Tags: logic-gates, datasheet, specifications, asic, nec

I'm looking for datasheets with specification for the NEC ASIC/Gate Arrays from around 1990.
More preciselly, any information with specifications of their ASIC/Gate Array lines.
I would like to known the typical gate count and things like that from devices from this era.
I understand that NEC was a big player during this time. I'm looking for any other information related to the specs of other brands.

Comment: https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/library/Datasheets-SW22/DSASW00427345.pdf

Comment: [Section 6 ASIC Technology Trends - Smithsonian Chip](http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/ASIC97/SECTION6.PDF). There appears to be timeline disparities involved here, NEC had several 1.5 um processes in 1989 (whether or not you qualify as a customer). You'd think state of the art was around 2.5 um.